# Compile Go into Shared Object for Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, go, java-native-interface

I would like to compile my Go library so that I can call it from Java via JNI on Raspberry Pi.

I am aware that I need to build the Go library into a .so (Shared Object) so that JNI can reference it. I have tried .a (Archive) but Java complains about invalid format.

I have been trying to run the following command but get the error shown below:

```
go install -buildmode=c-shared -linkshared SimpleLib
```

Error

```
-linkshared is only supported on linux/amd64
```

I am currently building via Mac OSX but does the error mean that I can only build from a Linux machine i.e. Ubuntu? Or is the error related to the required output.

Also, should I be looking into `gccgo`

Thanks

Comment: You need a Go compiler that generates ARM executables, not x86-64 executables for your Mac.

Comment: Ah ok, I got that. I thought that you could cross compile. Thanks.